# Json file not loading or showing alerts

Tags: jquery, html, json

This is a common question it seems but i cant for the life of me find out where exactly im goin wrong,  i have validated my json file and there are no errors, i could also swear tha t everythng was working perfectly at one point. im loading everything locally within one folder the following is my jquery file to load my json file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // loading json file
    var catelogue;
    var url = "shoppingItems.json";

    $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
        alert(json.shoppingItem[0].name);
    });
});
```

This is what my json file looks like and yes ive gone to http://jsonlint.com/ to validate

```
{
    "shoppingItem": [
        {
            "name": "LG Tone",
            "model_no": "HBS-730",
            "type": "Bluetooth Stereo",
            "price": "�45.00",
            "stock": 10,
            "images": "images/Headphones/lgtoneshbs.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "NoiseHush",
            "model_no": "NX22",
            "type": "Wired Headphones",
            "price": "�69.95",
            "stock": 10,
            "images": "images/Headphones/noisehushhead.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "NoiseHush",
            "model_no": "NX80",
            "type": "Earphones",
            "price": "�25.00",
            "stock": 10,
            "images": "images/Headphones/earpnoisehush.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "Motorola MOTOROKR",
            "model_no": "S305",
            "type": "Bluetooth Stereo",
            "price": "£35.00",
            "stock": 10,
            "images": "images/Headphones/earpnoisehush.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Nothing gets allerted, even if i try to alert the json file

Comment: try `console.log(json)` in your getJSON success callback and ensure by checking in firebug console that you are getting data as expected

Comment: Is your code running from a local `file:///` URL? AJAX does not work entirely consistently across browsers from local files, in most cases it does not work at all.

Comment: what happens if you just alert the json, instead of the items wihtin json?

Comment: It's probably unrelated to the problem but seeing `�` instead of `£` suggests there's something that needs a little fix.

Comment: It works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/YUuzG/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've replicated your solution on my machine and it works just fine. You just have to run your script over http:// instead of file:///.