# loading images from json file with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

So I have a json file which now loads text and images individually pretty fine, this is just a simple example of what I did to test if it would work:

```
  outputc+="<li>"
  outputc+=this.name+" "+this.price+"</li>";
  $('#featured').append(outputc);
  $("<img/>").attr('src',this.images).appendTo('#featured');
```

Using the above code works perfectly however i need for both of these to be wrapped with a list, so I did some searching and I found this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//loading json file

var url = "shoppingItems.json";

$.getJSON(url,function(json){


    $.each(json.shoppingItem,function()
    {
        var output ='<li><img src= "'+this.images+'" alt ="'+this.name+'"></li>';
    });

    $('.items').append(output);
});
});
```

The above jQuery doesn't bring back anything at all, there isn't anything wrong with my json file as it's been validated and the code works if I simply alert it. This is potentially something I must be doing wrong with my output script which I can't see.

My JSON file can be found here: [Json file not loading or showing alerts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789410/json-file-not-loading-or-showing-alerts)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you declare it inside the callback function as `var output`, the `output` variable is local to that callback function and vanishes once the loop is completed. Even if that wasn't the case, the use of the `=` operator would mean you were overwriting the previous value with each iteraction.

Try this:

```
var output = ""; // initialize it outside the loop
$.each(json.shoppingItem,function()
{
    output += '<li><img src= "'+this.images+'" alt ="'+this.name+'"></li>';
});
$('.items').append(output);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/zB5fv/

Comment: Thank you @Blazemonger, sorted the append has to be within the loop to show all images

Comment: It shouldn't need to be. Is your JSON larger than the sample you've provided?

Comment: Yes that maybe the reason it needs to be outside the loop